# BOBYQA optimizer IndexError

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, vqe

I'm trying to implement BOBYQA optimizer for my VQE job. Though, I'm facing the below issue. Can anyone help in pointing out what the actual cause of this issue is and how to solve this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [34], line 9
      7 # Run the custom VQE function and monitor execution time
      8 start = time()
----> 9 result = custom_vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(ham_16)
     10 end = time()
     12 print(result)

Cell In [32], line 30, in CustomVQE.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(self, operators, aux_operators)
     27 x0 = np.pi/4 * np.random.rand(self._circuit.num_parameters)
     29 # Run optimization
---> 30 res = self._optimizer.minimize(objective, x0=x0, bounds=None)
     32 # Populate VQE result
     33 result = VQEResult()

File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/bobyqa.py:69, in BOBYQA.minimize(self, fun, x0, jac, bounds)
     60 def minimize(
     61     self,
     62     fun: Callable[[POINT], float],
   (...)
     65     bounds: Optional[List[Tuple[float, float]]] = None,
     66 ) -> OptimizerResult:
     67     from skquant import opt as skq
---> 69     res, history = skq.minimize(
     70         func=fun,
     71         x0=np.asarray(x0),
     72         bounds=np.array(bounds),
     73         budget=self._maxiter,
     74         method="bobyqa",
     75     )
     77     optimizer_result = OptimizerResult()
     78     optimizer_result.x = res.optpar

File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skquant/opt/__init__.py:56, in minimize(func, x0, bounds, budget, method, options, **optkwds)
     53     import skquant.opt._norbitR as optimizer
     55 if optimizer is not None:
---> 56     return optimizer.minimize(func, x0, bounds, budget, options, **optkwds)
     58 raise RuntimeError('unknown optimizer "%s"' % method)

File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skquant/opt/_pybobyqa.py:27, in minimize(func, x0, bounds, budget, optin, **optkwds)
     24 objfunc = ObjectiveFunction(func, {'simple_function' : True })
     26 # massage bounds (force reshaping as bobyqa is picky)
---> 27 lower = numpy.asarray(bounds[:,0]).reshape(-1)
     28 upper = numpy.asarray(bounds[:,1]).reshape(-1)
     30 x0 = numpy.asarray(x0).reshape(-1)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Below is my code for the VQE algorithm:

```
class CustomVQE(MinimumEigensolver):
    
    def __init__(self, estimator, circuit, optimizer, callback=None):
        self._estimator = estimator
        self._circuit = circuit
        self._optimizer = optimizer
        self._callback = callback
        
    def compute_minimum_eigenvalue(self, operators, aux_operators=None):
                
        # Define objective function to classically minimize over
        def objective(x):
            # Execute job with estimator primitive
            job = self._estimator.run([self._circuit], [operators], [x])
            # Get results from jobs
            est_result = job.result()
            # Get the measured energy value
            value = est_result.values[0]
            # Save result information using callback function
            if self._callback is not None:
                self._callback(value)
            return value
            
        # Select an initial point for the ansatzs' parameters
        x0 = np.pi/4 * np.random.rand(self._circuit.num_parameters)
        
        # Run optimization
        res = self._optimizer.minimize(objective, x0=x0, bounds=None)
        
        # Populate VQE result
        result = VQEResult()
        result.cost_function_evals = res.nfev
        result.eigenvalue = res.fun
        result.optimal_parameters = res.x
        return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SciPy BOBYQA wrapper is expecting an array for bounds, not None. The array would be a tuple of lower and upper bound for each parameter. You can try passing `[(None, None)] * len(x0)` for bounds instead of None.